# Javascript, clear form after press OK in confirm window. But keeps form data if confirm is cancelled

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Writing a program for an assignment and no where in my book does it help with this case.

After the user enters in information for a drink order form, they hit a button that reads "Order", the button calls a function that calculates and displays a confirm window with required info

If the user clicks “ok” in the confirm message, an alert message should be displayed notifying the user that the order was placed and the form should be cleared, a function is needed

If the user clicks “cancel” in the confirm message, an alert message should be displayed notifying the user that the order was cancelled. The form should still contain all of the values that the user entered.

My issue is that I don't know what is needed to have the form reset when "OK" is selected in the confirm window. But if "Cancel" is selected, the values remain entered.

Here's what the code is so far

Javascript (Only entering confirm portion)

```
                   if (window.confirm("Fruit: " + document.drinkList.numFruit.value + ", Total: $" + totalFruit + ".00 \n"
                     + "Water: " + document.drinkList.numWater.value + ", Total: $" + totalWater + ".00 \n"
                     + "Coffee: " + document.drinkList.numCoffee.value + ", Total: $" + totalCoffee + ".00 \n"
                     + "Coke: " + document.drinkList.numCoke.value + ", Total: $" + totalCoke + ".00 \n"
                     + "Tea: " + document.drinkList.numTea.value + ", Total: $" + totalTea + ".00 \n"
                     + "Ice: " + document.drinkList.numIce.value + "\n"
                     + "Cream: " + document.drinkList.numCream.value + "\n"
                     + "Sugar: " + document.drinkList.numSugar.value + "\n"
                     + "Pinneapple Juice: " + document.drinkList.numPinn.value + "\n"
                     + "Lemon Juice: " + document.drinkList.numLemon.value + "\n\n"
                     + "Overall Total: " + (totalCoffee + totalCoke + totalFruit + totalTea + totalWater) + ".00 \n\n"
                     + "Confirm order?"))
            window.alert("The order was submitted!");

        else
            window.alert("The order was cancelled!");
```

HTML

```
        <button type="button"value="Order" onclick="calcAll()">
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('formId').reset()`

Comment: I suspect the name of your form is *drinkList*, so `document.drinkList.reset()` should do the job.

Comment: Is the javascript code part of the calcAll function?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated, really helped out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use pure javascript and do:

```
document.getElementById("form").reset();
```

Comment: If your question has been resolved, please select an answer so this question will be displayed as solved.

Comment: the "jQuery" part isn't using any jQuery. Why do you think it's even worth mentioning (jQuery, that is)?

Comment: Don't you think your answer is nothing but a **ctrl+c->ctrl+v** from *comments* ? `document.drinkList.reset();` is not jQuery!

Comment: In response to the above, I wanted to add an answer for him to accept so the question would show as answered on searches. Also, as mentioned in my answer, it states that this was already pointed out in the comments! :)